# Capturing optional regex segment with PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to check the end of a URL for the possible existence of /news_archive or /news_archive/5 in PHP. The below snippet does exactly what I want, but I know that I could achieve this with one `preg_match` rather than two. How can I improve this code to treat the /5 as an optional segment and capture it if it exists?

```
if (preg_match('~/[0-9A-Za-z_-]+_archive/[0-9]+$~', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $matches) || preg_match('~/[0-9A-Za-z_-]+_archive$~', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $matches)) {
    $page_info['parent_page']['page_label'] = ltrim($matches[0], '/');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider your first pattern:

```
~/[0-9A-Za-z_-]+_archive/[0-9]+$~
```

Let's break it down:

1. `/` a literal string `/`
2. `[0-9A-Za-z_-]+` one or more of `0-9`, `A-Z`, `a-z`, `_` or `-`
3. `_archive` a literal string `_archive`
4. `/` literal slash again
5. `[0-9]+` one or more digits
6. `$` the end of the string must follow the one or more digits

So basically you want to make #4 and #5 optional.  To be more specific, you want either both 4 and 5, or neither 4 nor 5.

Consider this:

`(a[b]+)?`

This means that you have one `a` followed by one or more `b`, and that this grouped a/b entity is optional.

Letting a be #4 and b be digits like in #5, we're left with:

`(/[0-9]+)?`

Or:

```
~/[0-9A-Za-z_-]+_archive(/[0-9]+)?$~
```

This will capture the entire group though, like `/5`:

```
php -r "preg_match('~/[0-9A-Za-z_-]+_archive(/([0-9]+))?$~', '/news_archive/5', $m); var_dump($m);"
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  string(15) "/news_archive/5"
  [1] =>
  string(2) "/5"
}
```

You can just add another group to remedy that though:

```
~/[0-9A-Za-z_-]+_archive(/([0-9]+))?$~
```

Example:

```
php -r "preg_match('~/[0-9A-Za-z_-]+_archive(/([0-9]+))?$~', '/news_archive/44', $m); var_dump($m);"
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(16) "/news_archive/44"
  [1] =>
  string(3) "/44"
  [2] =>
  string(2) "44"
}
```

You could technically make the outside group a non-capturing group (like `(?:/([0-9]+))?`), but I don't think the added complication is worth not grabbing the `/` part too.

(By the way, sorry if you're familiar with regex and you found this excessive.  I tend to take a very verbose approach to any regex related question :).)

Comment: This is a fantastic response, and certainly more than I expected. In a good way. I am fairly unfamiliar with regex itself, so the thorough analysis was a pleasant and refreshing lesson! Thank you.

Comment: @davo0105 Glad I could help! :)